# Trying to display what position the matrix editor is at

Tags: ti-basic

I have a TI-84 Plus CE (although I kind of want it to be backwards compatible, and compatible with the nSPIRE and TI-84 Plus)

I am trying to output onto the screen what position the matrix editor is at, and I am getting an `ERROR:syntax`, although (to the best of my knowledge about this language) the statement is valid.

my code is:

`:Input "NUM OF ROWS?",A
:Input "NUM OF COLUMNS?",B
:{A,B}->dim([A])
:For(R,1,A)
:For(C,1,B)
:Disp "LOCATION: ("R","C")"
:Input "VALUE?",E
:E->[A](C,D)
:End
:End
:ChiSquared-Test([A],[B])`

side note: i'm also getting a "divide by zero error" on the chi-squared test, for an unknown reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed The Problem!

FIX:
`Disp "Matrix Location:",{R,C}`

The Reason the error happened was because in TI Basic, the option to have variables displayed outside the text is not available, so you have to do a 2 line display with the description in the first line, and the matrix location in the next line.

`(R,C)` when in a `Disp` statement throw an error, so you need to use the curly brackets instead like so: `{R,C}.`